# What is the best way to update item in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm learning React Redux and i'm writing todo-list app. The last missing piece is option to editting selected item (onClick). I have problem with doing that.

Could you tell me how i can achieve that?

I looking for solution like that:

1. Select item which you want to update (by clicking on edit icon)
2. Form should change into "editing mode" so user can pass new value into editing item.
3. When value is passed, then user click on submit button.

[image]

I don't know how to make editing mode so my input form can handle updating existing item.

```
 // ACTION
    export const editTask = (task) => ({
      type: "EDIT_TASK",
      payload: task,
    });

     // REDUCER
        const INITIAL_STATE = {
          tasks: [],
          alert: {
            show: false,
            message: "",
            type: "",
          },
          isEditing: false,
        };
        
        const reducer = (state, action) => {
          switch (action.type) {
            case "EDIT_TASK":
              return {
                ...state,
                isEditing: true,
// take current tasks and updatedTask
                tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload],
                alert: setAlert(true, "Task has changed succesfull ", "success"),
              };
           default:
        return state;


On my todo.jsx

    const TasksTodo = () => {
      const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
      const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, INITIAL_STATE);
    
      const editTaskFromList = (item) => {
// match tasks from list with that selected
        const taskToEdit = state.tasks.find(
          (taskToFind) => taskToFind.id === item.id
        );
        const editedTask = {
          taskToEdit,
          title: inputValue,
        };
        dispatch(editTask([...state.tasks, editedTask]));
      };


 

     const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (inputValue) {
          const newItem = {
            id: new Date().getTime().toString(),
            title: inputValue,
          };
          dispatch(addNewTask(newItem));
          setInputValue("");
        } else {
          dispatch({ type: "NO_VALUE" });
        }
      };
    
      const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
      };


  

    return (
        <div className="tasks-list-section">
          <h3 className="tasks__title">tasks List </h3>
          {state.alert.show && (
            <Alert
              {...state.alert}
              removeAlert={() => dispatch(changeAlertState())}
            />
          )}
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="tasks__form">
            <input
              type="text"
              value={inputValue}
              placeholder="e.g homework"
              className="tasks__input"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <button type="submit" className="tasks__submit-btn">
              {state.isEditing ? "edit" : "submit"}
            </button>
          </form>
          {state.tasks.length > 0 && (
            <div className="tasks__container">
              <Tasks
                listItems={state.tasks}
                removeTask={removeTaskFromList}
                editTask={editTaskFromList}
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    };
        

   

TaskList Component:

    const Tasks = ({ listItems, editTask, removeTask }) => {
      return (
        <div className="tasks-list">
          {listItems.map((item) => {
            const { id, title } = item;
            return (
              <div key={id} className="tasks__item">
                <p className="tasks__item--title">{title}</p>
                <div className="tasks__button-group">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="tasks__button-group--edit"
                    onClick={() => editTask(item)}
                  >
                    <RiEditBoxLine className="size" />
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="tasks__button-group--delete"
                    onClick={() => removeTask(item)}
                  >
                    <RiDeleteBin6Line className="size" />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Please find the simple workaround for this.

**Page.js ( Main Component)**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { addTask, editTask, removeTask } from "./actions";

const TaskList = ({ tasks, removeTask, editTask }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {tasks.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <p>{item.title}</p>
          <button type="button" onClick={(e) => editTask(item)}>
            Edit
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={(e) => removeTask(item)}>
            Remove
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

function Page() {
  const tasks = useSelector((state) => state.tasks);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [editingTaskIndex, setEditingTaskIndex] = useState(null);

  const editTaskFromList = (task) => {
    const taskToEdit = tasks.find((item) => item.id === task.id);
    const taskIndex = tasks.indexOf(taskToEdit);
    setEditingTaskIndex(taskIndex);
    setInputValue(taskToEdit.title);
  };

  const removeTaskFromList = (task) => {
    const taskToDelete = tasks.find((item) => item.id === task.id);
    const taskIndex = tasks.indexOf(taskToDelete);
    dispatch(removeTask(taskIndex));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (editingTaskIndex === null) {
      const newItem = {
        id: new Date().getTime().toString(),
        title: inputValue
      };
      dispatch(addTask(newItem));
    } else {
      const editingItem = tasks[editingTaskIndex];
      editingItem.title = inputValue;
      dispatch(editTask(editingTaskIndex, editingItem));
    }
    setInputValue("");
    setEditingTaskIndex(null);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Task List</h3>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={inputValue}
          placeholder="e.g: homework"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>

      <TaskList
        tasks={tasks}
        editTask={editTaskFromList}
        removeTask={removeTaskFromList}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

**reducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  tasks: [],
  isEditing: false
};

function taskReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TASK":
      return { ...state, tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload] };
    case "EDIT_TASK":
      console.log(action.payload);
      const currentTasks = Array.from(state.tasks);
      currentTasks[action.payload.taskIndex] = action.payload.task;
      return { ...state, tasks: currentTasks };
    case "REMOVE_TASK":
      const allTasks = Array.from(state.tasks);
      allTasks.splice(action.payload, 1);
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: allTasks
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default taskReducer;
```

[Checkout the sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-task-list-react-redux-cfmn9)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Answers, like questions, should be specific and complete on their own. A *supporting* link is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your time but this solutions isn't simple for me. Your code looks complicated for me.

Comment: In your sandbox, in actionTypes.js the names are wrong `_DIK_TASK, ADA_TASK` change them back to EDIT and ADD and your sandbox works

Comment: @I3artosz which part do you find difficult to understand in this answer?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij My most difficult this for me is code in Reducer for case "EDIT_TASK". I'm not sure if it's good way to use indexOf array if i can find element by his id. In other side i found different solution and i think it's more efficient. I will post in in couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I found different solution. Rate my code if you can.

On my reducer

```
 case "EDIT_TASK":
      return {
        ...state,
        isEditing: true,
        tasks: [
          ...state.tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== action.payload.id),
          action.payload,
        ],
        alert: setAlert(true, "Task has changed succesfull ", "success"),
      };
```

tasks.jsx

```
const editTaskFromList = (item) => {
    const taskToEdit = state.tasks.find(
      (taskToFind) => taskToFind.id === item.id
    );
    setEditingTaskID(taskToEdit.id);
    setInputValue(taskToEdit.title);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (editingTaskID === null) {
      if (inputValue) {
        const newItem = {
          id: new Date().getTime().toString(),
          title: inputValue,
        };
        dispatch(addNewTask(newItem));
        setInputValue("");
      } else {
        alert("Value cannot be empty!");
      }
    } else {
      const editingItem = state.tasks.find((task) => task.id === editingTaskID);

      const newItem = { ...editingItem, title: inputValue };

      dispatch(editTask(newItem));
      setInputValue("");
      setEditingTaskID(null);
    }
  };
```